# Python: How to delete all rows which for each ID have only one value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas, looking like this:

```
ID     event
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       2
3       2
3       1
3       5
3       2
```

I would like to delete all rows, which for given ID have only one, same value in 'event' column. So my output should be:

```
   ID     event
    1       2
    1       3
    3       2
    3       1
    3       5
    3       2
```

because only ID = 2 has the same values in event column.
I tried iterating over ID, but it didn't give me appriopriate results. I know that solution should be simple here, but just can't come up with an idea.

Comment: what happens if there was e.g. another row with `ID=2` and `event=3`? Keep every row with `ID=2` or drop one?

Comment: Then it should be in the output, because has 2 different events, not only one.

Comment: Ah i see, you've already got the case covered with `ID=3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `df.groupby` with `dfGroupBy.transform` should do it:

```
In [1471]: df[df.groupby('ID')['event'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]
Out[1471]: 
   ID  event
0   1      2
1   1      3
4   3      2
5   3      1
6   3      5
7   3      2
```